# The op amp circuit doesn’t seem to work

Tags: operational-amplifier, eeg

I’m trying to make a crude EEG using two AD8428 op amps, each with a fixed gain of 2000.

The output doesn’t give me anything. I mean there is noise, but the noise remains even when there’s no power to the circuit. My oscilloscope does ripple when I first connect the battery, but there is nothing beyond that. Not even a clear 60Hz signal from power line interference.

Can you see anything I’ve perhaps done wrong?

[image]

Comment: What is the DC output voltage? Are you input bias resistors on the input? If not, the output will slammed against one of the rails.

Comment: Excite it with a small square wave in a circuit sim... Did you instead mean to use a comparator to compare to a buffered mean over time (low pass filtered reading)?

Comment: Small electrode offsets will blow out your second stage.

Answer (score 4):

The [AD8428 datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ad8428.pdf) tells us that the input offset voltage for these devices could be anything up to 23μV. Let's say it's just 10μV. In that case, even with the two "electrode" inputs tied together (or otherwise held at the same potential), the output of the first stage would be:

$$ V_{OUT1} = 2000 \times 10\mu V = 20mV $$

The second stage would *want* to produce something like:

$$ V_{OUT2} = 2000 \times V_{OUT1} = 40V $$

That might be negative, depending on the polarity of the input offset. In any case, the amplifiers can't produce +40V or -40V, since the supplies are ±4.5V, so in reality the output will be "stuck" at either maximum, approaching +4.5V or -4.5V.

The other issue is to do with the amplifiers "input voltage range". In general for op-amps and similar devices, you can't have either input potential fall outside of the power supply range. According to the AD8428 datasheet, input \$V_{IN}\$ should never get within 2.5V of the supplies. In your case, with supplies of ±4.5V:

$$ (-4.5V+2.5V) < V_{IN} < (+4.5V-2.5V) $$
$$ -2V < V_{IN} < +2V $$

Without the two inputs being constrained in some way to be within those bounds, the first stage amplifier will surely saturate or behave strangely. As you have it, neither input has any such constraint.

The usual way that EEGs solve this issue is by having a third electrode connecting the body to some known "bias" potential. You could use the ground node in your circuit for this. With the body "coerced" to be about 0V everywhere, then the other two electrodes will still be measuring the potential difference between two points, but their individual *average* potentials will be near 0V, conforming to the requirement \$-2V < V_{IN} < +2V\$.

Comment: Even with a driven leg, there are electrode potential differences, largely because of junction potentials between the electrode jelly and the skin, that get amplified as well.  State of the art is actually modest amplification and high-res (24-bit) sampling, giving you enough dynamic range to handle the amplified offset and enough resolution to see your signal.  Alternative is high-pass filtering after an inamp preamp stage, if your signal bandwidth doesn't go to DC